# Are the Baumslag-Solitar groups BS(n,n) and BS(n,-n) automata groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory

In this article of Bartholdi and Sunik http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603032, they say that BS(n,n) and BS(n,-n) are automata groups because they are virtually $F_{|n|}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ (where $F_{|n|}$ is the free group of rank $|n|$) following an article of Brunner & Sidki. I would like to know how to prove this statement. By advance thank you.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you mean by "this statement". Which statement?

Comment: In fact I meant both statements. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Presumably you have looked at the article by Brunner & Sidki?

Comment: yes I did. In that article, Brunner & Sidki want to prove that $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is an automaton group. But I think it's not the case. Anyway I don't see any link with the fact that $BS(n,n)$ is an automaton group, $F_{|n|}\rtimes\mathbb{Z},$ and the fact $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is an automaton group. The only link (which is false) I see is even if $BS(n,n)$ is a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ and $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is an automaton group, it does not make $BS(n,n)$ an automaton group.

Answer (score 3):

Begin with $BS(n,n)=\langle t,x\mid tx^nt^{-1}=x^n\rangle$. Let $L$ be the kernel of the homomorphism $BS(n,n)\to\mathbf{Z}$, $t\mapsto 0$, $x\mapsto 1$. Using the action of $BS(n,n)$ on its standard Bass-Serre tree shows that $L$ is free. It is generated by the $x^mtx^{-m}$ when $m$ ranges over $\mathbf{Z}$, but since this sequence is $n$-periodic, $m$ ranging over $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$ is enough. It can be shown that this is a free family but I won't check it since this is enough to show that $L$ is free of rank $\le n$, which is enough for your purposes. Now $x^n$ is central and $L\times\langle x^n\rangle$ has finite index.

For $BS(n,-n)=\langle t,x:tx^nt^{-1}=x^{-n}\rangle$, we need to consider the subgroup $H$ of index 2 kernel of the homomorphism mapping $x$ to $0$ and $t$ to 1 mod 2. It has the presentation, denoting $u=t^2$ and $y=tx^{-1}t^{-1}$: $\langle u,x,y\mid x^n=y^n, tx^nt^{-1}=x^n,ty^nt^{-1}=y^n\rangle$. But the latter is also isomorphic to a subgroup of index 2 in $BS(n,n)$ (kernel of the same homomorphism, but with $y$ defined as $txt^{—1}\in BS(n,n)$ instead). This yield a (free $\times$ infinite cyclic) subgroup of finite index, but rather $F_{2n-1}\times\mathbf{Z}$ than $F_n\times\mathbf{Z}$ (although I don't claim there's no $F_n\times\mathbf{Z}$ of finite index).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why does this property make $BS(n,n)$ an automaton group?

Comment: As pointed out by Derek, your question is ambiguous. My guess was that you understand that (1) being virtually $\mathbf{Z}\times F_k$ implies being automata group and that you were asking (2) why $BS(n,\pm n)$ has this virtual property. If you're asking why (1) holds, somebody else could answer better than me.

Comment: yes I'm also asking why (1) holds

Comment: I never heard of "standard Bass-Serre tree" of a group? What is it?

Comment: For a group there's no "standard Bass-Serre tree". But for Baumslag-Solitar groups there's one: indeed they are defined as HNN extension of an infinite cyclic group, and the corresponding Bass-Serre tree is the one I call "standard", the action is with cyclic edge and vertex stabilizers, and in restriction to $L$ the vertex stabilizers are trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Yves's answer explains why $BS(n,\pm n)$ is virtually (a free group) x $\mathbb Z$. In particular, it is linear over $\mathbb Z$, and so may be generated by automata. This is the statement in the article [BS].